# Error when merging rasters in QGIS

Tags: qgis, raster, qgis-3, merge

I'm using QGIS 3.8 with GRASS. I have three rasters that are located far from each other and I would like to merge them into one raster layer.

I managed to merge two of them but the third one makes problem (I tried also all the three but it didn't work).

I got this error message:

> ```
> Loading resulting layers The following layers were not correctly generated.
> C:/this/is/a/path/Temp/processing_e3ae725664cf414481ec8d6bc10a25b3/c955b92928c545d29bc4ec3040703495/OUTPUT.tif
> You can check the 'Log Messages Panel' in QGIS main window to find more information about the execution of the algorithm.
> ```

I have created the problematic layer again but it didn't work. I don't know if it has to do with their distance from each other:

[image: example]

The blue is the merged ones and the red is the problematic raster.

My end goal is to have all of the three rasters in one layer. How can I achieve it?

Comment: Run **gdalinfo each_raster** for watching Pixel Size and other possible aligning issues.

Comment: where should I run this command

Comment: In OSGeo Console (similar to MSDos Console) into QGIS 3.8 folder.

Comment: I get error message : No such file ot directory . It;s the first time I use this consule so maybe I don't know how to really acess my rasters. However in my Log panel, it says: 2019-11-07T10:10:48     INFO    GDAL execution console output
             ERROR 3: Free disk space available is 56180699136 bytes, whereas 89407942624 are at least necessary. You can disable this check by defining the CHECK_DISK_FREE_SPACE configuration option to FALSE.
             
             Creation failed, terminating gdal_merge.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem with my DEM merging.
Finally, I launched the QGIS desktop 3.8.3, where everything was fine.
Alternatively, you can use SAGA for it. Both ways are under the link below:

[QGIS Digital Elevation Model merging problem](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/349191/qgis-digital-elevation-model-merging-problem)