# QGIS Digital Elevation Model merging problem

Tags: qgis, dem

I am encountering the problem with merging 2 raster digital elevation model layers (.tiff).

[image]

The Qgis 3.10 returns an error as follows:

[image]

The following layers were not correctly generated.

- C:/Users/mariuszk/AppData/Local/Temp/processing_9cbcbd1489014d3c90818bbf3b042cd0/processing_6bf82a76e8dc4750a515f3e1cb74f3df/f04e984630ff4005988a2ca741ed03b6/OUTPUT.tif

You can check the 'Log Messages Panel' in QGIS main window to find more information about the execution of the algorithm.

I don't know, where the problem can be.

There is a similar question [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/340929/qgis-error-with-merging-rasters), but not resolved, unfortunately.

It looks like there is a bug in the QGIS 3.10 version, still not resolved from older versions.

https://issues.qgis.org/issues/18215

https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/issues/29346
https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/issues/30095

The Github says, that it might be a bug:

https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/issues/33677
https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/issues/33386

Is there another way to make this merge?

Comment: Please post the real error message from the protocol. Also check whether your installation is correct.

Comment: I already edited

Comment: Great, you copy-pasted the same text which is in your screenshot, while the information from the protocol is probably the one we need.

Comment: So to looks like I don't know where is the protocol then. 

In the Parameters in the GDAL/OGR section I found:
python3 -m gdal_merge -ot Float32 -of GTiff -o C:/Users/mariuszk/AppData/Local/Temp/processing_9cbcbd1489014d3c90818bbf3b042cd0/processing_6bf82a76e8dc4750a515f3e1cb74f3df/d94ff82c5ea7400db5ad0ed812ae872c/OUTPUT.tif --optfile C:/Users/mariuszk/AppData/Local/Temp/processing_9cbcbd1489014d3c90818bbf3b042cd0/processing_6bf82a76e8dc4750a515f3e1cb74f3df/fbbd57bd798e40da84ba009af41027c2/mergeInputFiles.txt

Comment: As stated in the error message you copied: "check the 'Log Messages Panel'".

Comment: According to this query:
https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/84790/where-does-qgis-write-its-error-log-messages
I run the python console and got sth like this:
QgsApplication.messageLog().messageReceived.connect(write_log_message)
<PyQt5.QtCore.QMetaObject.Connection object at 0x0000013AC9787588>

Comment: Looks suspiciously like other reports of broken environment variables, like [question 344713](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/344713/qgis-3-python-doesnt-find-gdal-module). Try [this method](https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/issues/33386#issuecomment-569140502)

Comment: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/282115/enable-on-the-fly-crs-transformation-in-qgis-3 I am getting something like this

Answer (score 0):

After launching the QGIS 3.8.3 desktop via OSGeo instead of QGIS 3.10 I found, that everything is working.

[image]

The bug exists in some 3x versions, as described on the GitHub:

https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/issues/29346 https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/issues/30095

https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/issues/33677 https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/issues/33386

[image]

Alternatively is an option to merge the DEM files in the SAGA as per the link below:

http://geoinfor.pl/2019/07/09/laczenie-rastrowych-nmt-w-saga-gis/

written in Polish, but the SAGA interface screenshots are in English.